# Getting mouse click position in a Plane/Cube world Space

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi2,

This seems to be an easy problem to fix.,
but i still cannot figure it on my own.

I need to be able to find the position of my mouse click at the 3D plane at world space which corresponding to plane's scale.

For example:
[image]
if i click the point a in my game view., it should return me 0,0f
The MainCamera however, can do move around.



[image]
and then if click point C it should return me a Vector2 which (i believe) should correspond with the scaling of the 3d object



[image]
and clicking inside the 3D plane, should once again return me a Vector2 according to the Object's scaling.

I know that i can use `Input.mousePosition` but it just return me the mouse position without any relation to the plane object itself.

Comment: Converting mouse position from screen to world coordinate system should be a farily common problem (see [this article](https://gamedevbeginner.com/how-to-convert-the-mouse-position-to-world-space-in-unity-2d-3d/)).

Answer (score 0):

There is " Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint" that converts to in game position.
here:
https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html